# How to add hash keys to Wordpress tags

Tags: wordpress, web, hash, tags

I'm building a website about music chords.
Sharp chords look like this example: F#m7b5.
That chord (F#m7b5) can be called in many other way like:

F# half-diminished,
F# minor seventh flat fifth,
F# minor seventh flat five,
F#m7b5,
F#∅,
F#m7(b5),
F#º7,
F#1/2dim,
F#1/2dim7,
F#m7(-5),
Fa# ∅,
Fa# m7b5,
Fa# m7(b5)

I would like that my users will find my F#m7b5 post searching for any of the alternative nomenclature so I've added those as tags but Wordpress doesn't accept the hash keys into tags and after a post update all hash keys disappear.

There's a proper way to add hash keys into tags?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't believe it is possible in standard WP - you can only use alphanumeric characters, `-`and `_`. However this looks more like you are asking about what WP can do rather than being a programming-related question, SO is a site for programming-related questions. If this is related to programming in some way, please edit your question to explain how and let us know exactly what you are trying to do in your code so we can help.

Comment: I was hoping that I could find a way to edit some Wordpress files in order to force it to  accept the hash keys into tags. If I'm still out of topic, accept my apologises. Thank you

Comment: No its not off topic if you are looking for a programming-related answer. However I'm not sure you *need* a programming answer... you can create tags where the tag *name* and tag *slug* are different. Re-reading your question, I think this is what you need? WP already does that, so what version of WP are you using? If you've an older version of WP, you might just need to upgrade. If you are trying change the *slug* to have a `#` then that's probably not possible - even in code - because it wouldn't be valid in the URL.

Comment: Yes: the slug can be different from tags but this doesn't solve my problem. In URL I could use "%23" instead of hash key, some browsers will convert automatically the %23 in a hash. The problem is related to tags: since a sharp chord has the hash in its name, I need to add it to all name variations. Those variations (see my example in my first message) should point to my post, so if someone is searching for F#m7(b5), he will find it as F#m75b because I've added F#m7(b5) as tag for F#m7b5. Wordpress keeps deleting the hash so my tag became Fm7(b5) which is a different chord.

Comment: Ok, I see now... you technically *could* use the slug WP creates, except that slug has a different semantic meaning in your site. Maybe you could try hooking into the code before the tag is saved and replace the `#` with `_` which *is* an allowed character. There are `create_term` and `edit_term` hooks, but they fires *after* the term is saved. Might still be worth looking into though!

Comment: There's a way to set "create_term" and "edit_term" hooks for all posts? The fact that they fire after the term is saved it's not a problem. I'm not into programming but if you give me some instruction I can try to tweak Wordpress code. Thank you

Comment: Is it the slug of the term or the page you need to change? I thought you wanted to change the *tag* slug, which would need a hook (similar to `create_term`  or `edit_term`)  that would change the slug before it gets saved? I'm afraid I've never done anything like that so I can't really help. But now I'm wondering if its actually the slug for the *post* that you want to change? You can change that in the page editor itself. And if it's neither of those things, I'm confused and you might need to edit your question to explain it a bit more :)

Comment: Every posts in Wordpress has tags attached. Tags are words which point to their related posts. Forget about slug or URL, slug is not a problem. Follow this example: I have a post called "Dogs" and I have added 4 tags like"Golden retriever", "German Shepherd", "Bulldog" and "Beagle" so an user that search for "Beagle" on my website will find my post called "Dogs". Now imagine that Wordpress doesn't allow the letter "g" in tags. At this point my tags will be "Olden Retriever", "Erman Shepherd", "Bulldo" and "Beale" and the user who is searching for "Beagle" will never find my post "Dogs".